# How to fix 'Replacement has [x] rows, data has [y]' error within custom ggplot2 function?

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, environment-variables

#### Problem

I'm making a function to make nice violin plots using ggplot2 that also give means, 95% bootstrapped confidence intervals, and group comparisons. When I use the exact names of the variables inside my function, it works. When I use different names, I get the famous "Replacement has [x] rows, data has [y]" error.

#### Hypothesis

I know that this error usually arises because a non-existent object is used. Thus, I suspect this has to do with different levels of local and global variables/environments, in particular in relation to the rcompanion::dataSummary function (for the 95% CI) within my function that doesn't seem to accept differently named arguments, but I'm stuck and can't quite figure it out.

#### Code and minimally reproducible example

My custom function:

```
# Nice Violin Plot Function
niceViolin <- function (Data=Data,Group=Group,Response=Response,ManualColour=F,ylabel,compare=F,comp1=NULL,comp2=NULL) {
  class(Data$Response) <- "numeric"
  if(!require(rcompanion)){install.packages("rcompanion") + library(rcompanion)}
  dataSummary <- groupwiseMean(Response ~ Group, 
                               data   = Data, 
                               conf   = 0.95, 
                               digits = 3,
                               R      = 2000,
                               boot        = TRUE,
                               traditional = FALSE,
                               normal      = FALSE,
                               basic       = FALSE,
                               percentile  = FALSE,
                               bca         = TRUE)
  if(!require(ggplot2)){install.packages("ggplot2") + library(ggplot2)}
  if(!require(ggsignif)){install.packages("ggsignif") + library(ggsignif)}
  ggplot(Data, aes(x = factor(Group), y = Response, fill = factor(Group))) + 
    theme_grey(base_size = 24) +
    {if (ManualColour == TRUE) scale_fill_manual(values=c("#00BA38", "#619CFF", "#F8766D"))} +
    ylab(ylabel) +
    geom_violin() +
    geom_point(aes(y = dataSummary$Mean), color = "black", size = 4, data = dataSummary) + 
    geom_errorbar(aes(y = dataSummary$Mean, ymin = dataSummary$Bca.lower, ymax = dataSummary$Bca.upper),
                  color = "black", size = 0.5, width = 0.2, data = dataSummary) + 
    theme(legend.position = "none", axis.title.x=element_blank(),
          axis.text.x = element_text(colour="black"), axis.text.y = element_text(colour="black")) +
    if (compare == TRUE) {geom_signif(comparisons = list(c(comp1, comp2)), 
                                      map_signif_level=TRUE, size= 1.3, textsize=8)
    }
}
```

If I name my variables "Group" and "Response", it works.

```
Response <- sample(x = 1:20, size = 50, replace = TRUE)
Group <- sample(x = 1:2, size = 50, replace = TRUE)
Dataset <- data.frame(Group,Response)
niceViolin(Data = Dataset, Group = Group, Response = Response, ManualColour = F, ylabel = "Dependent Variable", compare = T, comp1 = 1, comp2 = 2)
```

If I name my column names something else, it doesn't work.

```
# If I name my column names something else, it doesn't work.
names(Dataset) <- c("Condition","Outcome")
niceViolin(Data = Dataset, Group = Condition, Response = Outcome, ManualColour = F, ylabel = "Dependent Variable", compare = T, comp1 = 1, comp2 = 2)
 Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "Response", value = numeric(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 50
```

#### Question

I expect that when my column names are named differently from my function defaults, it works nonetheless. Any idea why this is not the case, and how to workaround this?

Comment: In the second line of your niceViolin function, you are trying to access Data$Response, but the dataframe passed to the function doesn't have a variable 'Response' - just Outcome. You'll also run into a problem with your ggplot statement, where you pass the Data dataframe again, and try to reference Group and Response variables there too. Part of the problem is passing the whole dataframe (Data), and the Group and Response vectors separately to the function

Comment: This question was closed as off-topic because of "a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error". The sample code still works for me, but I suspect it might not work for people who have not installed the required packages. Therefore, I slightly edited the code to install the necessary packages, if they are not installed when trying the sample code. It should work now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to pass the whole data frame and vectors separately (see comment above). If you want to be flexible on variable names, the quickest way to fix this might be:

```
niceViolin <- function (Group, Response, ManualColour=F, ylabel, compare=F, comp1=NULL, comp2=NULL) {
  Data <- data.frame(Group, Response)
```

And then call the function as follows:

```
niceViolin(Group = Dataset$Condition, Response = Dataset$Outcome, ManualColour = F, ylabel = "Dependent Variable", compare = T, comp1 = 1, comp2 = 2)
```

Comment: Then I think we agree the "[x] rows" error wasn't the culprit. I'd like to retitle my post to better convey the problem which your solution has solved, but I can't think of something good and clear. What title would you use to convey the problem in few words?

Comment: hmmm...maybe something related to passing entire dataframe vs. specific column vectors as arguments to a custom function...